# Facebook FQL getting all my friends last checkin

Tags: android, facebook-fql

i'm trying to use FQL to get all my Facebook friends last Checkin.
since i have lots of friends the FQL query took forever so I've narrow it down to the friends which their current location is the same city as mine:

```
 SELECT author_uid, coords FROM checkin WHERE author_uid IN 
(SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid IN
(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND current_location.city IN
(SELECT current_location.city FROM user WHERE uid = me()))
```

**My questions:**

1. for each user i get 5 lines. is there a way to get only 5 line for each user ?
2. is there some kind of way to do a GROUP BY maybe ?
3. this is not exactly what i was looking for... will be happy to hear suggestions

Comment: its about time that StackOverFlow will not allow Down vote without comment.. its just rude

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting `"exceeded the rate of 600 calls per 600 seconds"`

just refresh your `access token`

`/me/friends?fields=checkins.limit(<>)` will do the trick for you.

or

if you want to use `fql` then,

```
SELECT checkin_id FROM checkin WHERE author_uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

It will give you your friend's checkins.

If you also want those checkins in which your friends are tagged then use follwoing query:

```
SELECT checkin_id FROM checkin WHERE author_uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 =

 me()) OR tagged_uids IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be easier to do with the Graph API than with FQL. This will get you the most recent checkin of all your friends.

```
/me/friends?fields=checkins.limit(1)
```

There is no `SELECT UNIQUE` syntax in FQL, so you would need to filter the result in your client application. You could use `ORDER BY` to sort these.

Comment: this is causing (#613) Calls to checkin_fql have exceeded the rate of 600 calls per 600 seconds.

Comment: How are you making the call to the API?

Comment: i'm trying it throw the graph api explorer for now.. exactly as you wrote